# Can R plot a histogram *without* doing the frequency count? My data already consists of (item, count) pairs

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

All the examples I see from R hist() starts with a raw list of data, and does the frequency counts in R.  My data is not raw, it's already counted and binned, for instance
A, 34
B, 15
C, 82
D, 22

Can R begin with data in that form and plot a histogram from it *without* doing the frequency counting form me?  Thanks - Ed

Comment: use a bar graph instead

Answer (score 2):

You **could** do so by assigning the class `histogram` to your data with your values in the appropriately named locations, and then using `plot.histogram`,  but since what you have is not a set of binned samples in the first place, you don't have data that is amenable to a true histogram.  As Tyler commented, just do a bar plot and assign your data category names to the x-axis.

Comment: Cheers for that, @Tyler and Carl.  Yes, you're quite right, I was too fixated on doing it one way to look at the more appropriate alternative.  Thanks again - Ed

Answer (score 1):

The new [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/) package on CRAN includes a private function `.BuildHistogram` that does exactly this.  It takes a list of breakpoints and a list of counts (breakpoints must be 1 greater than counts), and returns a valid R histogram object with the midpoints, density, and other object components setup properly so you can plot the resulting object with standard R functions.

```
install.packages("HistogramTools")
library(HistogramTools)
myhist <- HistogramTools:::.BuildHistogram(1:6, 1:5)
plot(myhist)
```

Comment: Hi @MurrayStokely - Cheers for that!  I've taken a few months off on my thesis - at your alma mater, no less - but now I'm back to working on it, and this is just what I wanted.  Thanks again, and cheers - Ed